# Android Hilt throw IllegalStateException even stated Custom Application in Manifest.xml

Tags: java, android, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

I have a few real devices and also tested with Android studio's emulator and did not find any similar crash.

My problem is that I published the app and received crash reports from real users.

Google Play Console Crash Report

> Type
> java.lang.RuntimeException
> ...
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
> at dagger.hilt.android.internal.managers.ActivityComponentManager.createComponent (ActivityComponentManager.java:76)
> at dagger.hilt.android.internal.managers.ActivityComponentManager.generatedComponent (ActivityComponentManager.java:66)
> at MyApp.Hilt_FirstEntryPage.generatedComponent (Hilt_FirstEntryPage.java:45)
> at MyApp.Hilt_FirstEntryPage.inject (Hilt_FirstEntryPage.java:67)
> at MyApp.Hilt_FirstEntryPage$1.onContextAvailable (Hilt_FirstEntryPage.java:38)
> at androidx.activity.contextaware.ContextAwareHelper.dispatchOnContextAvailable (ContextAwareHelper.java:99)
> at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onCreate (ComponentActivity.java:322)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate (FragmentActivity.java:249)
> at MyApp.FirstEntryPage.onCreate (FirstPage.java:68)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:8207)
> ...

ActivityComponentManager.java:76

```
Hilt Activity must be attached to an @HiltAndroidApp Application. Did you forget to specify your Application's class name in your  
 manifest's <application />'s android:name attribute?
```

I did check other stack overflow questions, I already did add my custom application into Manifest and run successfully in my testing devices.

My app has only one module and only one application, and also some several **ContentProvider**, **BroadcastReceiver**, **AppWidgetProvider**, **WorkManager**, **JobIntentService**, not sure they could affect the normal initialization of application to lead the crash.

For the FirstEntryPage activity, I did not inject any things. It is very simple activity page just like Hello World example. Therefore there could not be any component conflict. In addition, FirstEntryPage activity can be opened by **PendingIntent** from **BroadcastReceiver** and also notification.

The previous version did not apply hilt, and this version is the first time to bring hilt to real users.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
```

MyApplication.java

```
@HiltAndroidApp
public final class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication implements Configuration.Provider
```

FirstEntryPage.java

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
public final class FirstEntryPage extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener, DialogInterface.OnClickListener
```

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
   classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.40.1'
}

apply plugin: 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'  

dependencies {
   implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-work:1.0.0'
   implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.38.1'
   kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0'
   kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.38.1'
}
```

Comment: Are you using `Proguard`? Usually crashes which are not reproduced in the dev builds and show up in production are usually proguard issues. Create a prod minified build, enable debug logging (disable debugging), and run the app on your phone. You should see the crash reproduce.

Comment: @UdayadityaBarua Yes, I used `Proguard` in my project, but I didn't add any extra `Proguard` config when I started to use hilt.

Comment: Also, I tested both prod and dev builds, none of them can reproduce the case on my side.
In my Google Play Console's statistics, this crash occupies 2% of total crash. It seems not happen for everyone, and currently only happen for Android 9 to Android 12 users.

Comment: facing exactly same issue in FirebaseMessagingService. Not reproducible but can see rare case reports at playstore.

Answer (score 4):

After searching answer in the Internet, I found the answer in the dagger Github https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2798. I also tested by myself and there is no more such crash report in my Google Play Console after related code changes.

Here is the short answer:
When using hilt, you cannot use **Android Auto Backup** (`android:allowBackup="true"` without `android:backupAgent`), otherwise your app will crash.

If your app needs backup, with hilt, you must use **Key/Value Backup (Android Backup Service)** instead of **Android Auto Backup**.

That is, add these (and with your implementation of MyBackupAgent) in your AndroidManifest.xml

- `android:allowBackup="true"`
- `android:backupAgent="MyBackupAgent"`
- `android:fullBackupOnly="false"`

If you app does not need backup, with hilt, just set `android:allowBackup="false"` in your AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 1):

You also need to declare `@AndroidEntryPoint` in your parent activity of your `FirstEntryPage` Fragment Activity.

Comment: Sorry, I should mention `FirstEntryPage` extends `androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity`, therefore itself is the parent.