# IllegalStateException: Hilt Activity must be attached to an @HiltAndroidApp Application

Tags: android, dependency-injection, crash, dagger-hilt

We have an app that is published and used by thousands of users. But we noticed this crash on 3 devices, that occurred 14 times total (HONOR HNNTN (HONOR 50 Lite) (11 Android, 30 SDK); SAMSUNG M23XQ (GALAXY F23 5G) (Android 13, SDK 33); SAMSUNG R8S (Android 13, SDK 33))

What is interesting with this crash is that I saw it on Play Market, and nothing in Crashlytics

The error message and stack trace are below:

```
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException:
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:4078)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:4286)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:93)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:149)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:103)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2524)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:109)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:228)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8689)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:613)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1085)
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Hilt Activity must be attached to an @HiltAndroidApp Application. Did you forget to specify your Application's class name in your manifest's <application />'s android:name attribute?
at dagger.hilt.android.internal.managers.ActivityComponentManager.createComponent (ActivityComponentManager.java:76)
at dagger.hilt.android.internal.managers.ActivityComponentManager.generatedComponent (ActivityComponentManager.java:66)
at ru.scid.ui.Hilt_MainActivity.generatedComponent (Hilt_MainActivity.java:45)
at ru.scid.ui.Hilt_MainActivity.inject (Hilt_MainActivity.java:67)
at ru.scid.ui.Hilt_MainActivity$1.onContextAvailable (Hilt_MainActivity.java:38)
at androidx.activity.contextaware.ContextAwareHelper.dispatchOnContextAvailable (ContextAwareHelper.java:99)
at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onCreate (ComponentActivity.java:352)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate (FragmentActivity.java:217)
at ru.scid.ui.MainActivity.onCreate (MainActivity.kt:50)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:8327)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:8310)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1323)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:4049)
```

I have annotated the app with @HiltApplication obviously and all activities with @AndroidEntryPoint, as the app works for a lot of other users perfectly

What can be a cause of this weird crash?

This is our manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="my.package">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <application
        android:name=".App"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id"/>

        <service
            android:name="my.package.core.util.AppFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <receiver
            android:name="my.package.core.util.AlarmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="${applicationId}.SOME_NOTIFICATION" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter
                android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:host="@string/app_host" android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:host="@string/app_host" android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
            tools:node="remove">
        </provider>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is the app class:

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class App : Application(), Configuration.Provider {

    companion object {
        private lateinit var _instance: App

        fun getInstance(): App {
            return _instance
        }

    }

    init {
        _instance = this

        MapKitFactory.setApiKey(Constants.MAPKIT_API_KEY)
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        createTimber()
    }

    private fun createTimber() {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Timber.plant(Timber.DebugTree())
        }
    }

    @Inject
    lateinit var hiltWorkerFactory: HiltWorkerFactory

    override fun getWorkManagerConfiguration(): Configuration {
        return Configuration.Builder()
            .setWorkerFactory(hiltWorkerFactory)
            .build()
    }

}
```

I tried to reproduce this crash on Samsung A22S and on Poco X3 Pro, couldn't reproduce it.

Comment: Probably the same problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72224270/4244605

Comment: @t0m yeah, seems like it is the same problem. Thanks! Didn't try the suggested solutions yet